# I want to time-shift a webinar on Linux

Tags: linux, streaming, screen-recorder

These days I happen to follow webinars or discussions with little or no interaction from the public, be they on Zoom, Teams, Edumeet or whatever. I mean, I often do not need to look at them in real time. It strikes me that on Linux I have apparently no way to pause the video, go to the bathroom or brew a tea and come back to restart where I left.

Is there any simple way to do that on Linux?

I can record audio and video using SimpleScreenRecorder, but that does not solve my problem.

I even tried a convoluted solution using Xpra and SimpleScreenRecorder on a different X display, but as soon as I detach from the Xpra display, the recording freezes (it does not stop, simply it stays frozen on the last image), so this is not useful either.

I looked on the web for time-shifting a video or webinar, but all I get is tons of false positives.  Any pointers/suggestions?

Comment: Vlc can do what SimpleScreenRecorder can, and maybe less, because apparently it has problems with recording audio. As I explained, I need a time-shift functionality.